# Association has_and_belongs_to_many give validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I have two models, Inventor and Request, both of which have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. When I try to use the code in my control

```
request = Request::Patent.create(steps: JSON.parse(File.read('lib/steps_pops.json'))["Patente"])
inventors_id = JSON.parse(inventors_list_params[:id])
inventors_id.each{ |id| request.inventors << Inventor.find(id) }
```

I get an Inventor validation error (this is because it performs my Inventor model validation), but my goal is not to create a new user but to add its reference to the invention.

Comment: Can you show the code for your models and migrations as well as the error you are getting?

Comment: You need to fill the join table with the ids. Some xtra info on model and error would be nice.